# What do we call these people?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, terminology

1. A person who says that everything in this life is not **permanent** / is a **lie**.
2. A person who believes in things only after he has **seen/experienced** them.

Comment: With respect to "everything in this life is not permanent / is a lie.", are you asking about a disbelief in the universe?

Comment: @ThirdNews yes a disbelief in the existence of the universe other than the sun, earth, moon.

Comment: nulliverse (plural nulliverses)

    (philosophy) The world, regarded as having no rationality or rules. -Wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be referring to:

1) a [disbeliever](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Disbeliever)

2)a skeptic, also a doubting [Thomas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubting_Thomas).